# Display reactive values in bslib value_box without destryoing formatting

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, bslib

The [value boxes in bslib](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/value-boxes.html#hello-value_box) are attractive and fulfill a need when dashboarding. However, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to populate them with reactive (non-static) values without breaking the formatting and therefore reducing the power to communicate important results.

Here's output from my example app (*code at bottom*)

[image: Example app output]

The `value` in the bottom `value_box` will respond to the slider, but `textOutput` and similar functions wrap it in a `<p>` tag and that makes it so that the value is no longer formatted.

Is there a clean way to put a reactive value in my value_box without messing up my formatting?

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- bslib::page(
  
      # Input: Slider ----
      sliderInput(inputId = "number",
                  label = "number to display",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),
      
      # Output: Value Box Formatted ----
      bslib::value_box(
        title = "Good formatting", 
        value = 30
      ),
    
      # Output: Value Box Broken formatting ----
      bslib::value_box(
        title = "Bad formatting",
        value = textOutput("out_text")
      )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$out_text <- renderText(input$number)
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will [improve in the future](https://github.com/rstudio/bslib/issues/573), but for now, I would change `textOutput("out_text")` `textOutput("out_text", container = h2)`

Comment: Sorry, it took a while to accept your answer. I think this is the cleanest way to do this for the problem as I posed it. Since the prominent text in the value-box is an h2, this is substantially, the same as passing in a value in the way that one would hope. 

Once I got into it, I liked the flexibility of using the renderUI as I ended up suggesting because it gives the flexibility to change the glyph and the background color, but that was beyond the question I originally posed.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest answer, since you're shifting most of your UI for the value_box onto the server and breaking the whole zen-of-shiny.

But, I got it to work using you can use `renderUI` to populate the value on the server side so that it's directly consumed by the value-box rather than being wrapped in a `<p>` or a `<div>` or a `<span>`.

If you can come up with a cleaner solution where most of my UI can stay in the `ui` you can have the accepted answer and the accompanying glory and internet points.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- bslib::page(
  
  # Input: Slider ----
  sliderInput(inputId = "number",
              label = "number to display",
              min = 1,
              max = 50,
              value = 30),
  
  # Output: Value Box fixed formatting ----
  uiOutput("fixed_vb")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$fixed_vb <- renderUI({
    bslib::value_box(
      title = "Fixed formatting",
      value = input$number
    ) 
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```