# Dynamically change the class of a bslib value box in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, bslib

I use a `value_box` from the [bslib-package](https://rstudio.github.io/bslib/articles/value-boxes/index.html) to display values in a Shiny dashboard. The shown value depends on user input via various selectors which requires me to dynamically update the value box. This works well for the title and value using the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76292287/display-reactive-values-in-bslib-value-box-without-destryoing-formatting).

However, I also want to change the class of the value box depending on the value: E.g. if the value is below a certain threshold, show a red value box, if it's high show a green one.

Here's an MWE to illustrate my approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

test_df <- tibble(id = 1:2, 
                  title = c("low value","high value"), 
                  value = c(30, 80))

ui <- page_fixed(
  selectInput("select_id", "Selected ID", choices = 1:2, selected = 1),
  value_box(title = textOutput("vbox_title"),
            value = textOutput("vbox_value"),
            class = textOutput("vbox_class")
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  subset_df <- reactive({
    test_df %>%
      filter(id == input$select_id)
  })
  
  output$vbox_title <- renderText({
    subset_df() %>%
      pull(title)
  })

  output$vbox_value <- renderText({
    subset_df() %>%
      pull(value)
  })
  
  output$vbox_class <- renderText({
    value <- subset_df() %>%
      pull(value)
  
    ifelse(value > 50, "bg-success", "bg-warning")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Unfortunately, the text output for the class gets processed as `div list(id = &quot;vbox_class&quot;, class = &quot;shiny-text-output&quot;) list()` and I cannot figure out how to just pass the raw string to the class argument. I have already tried using `verbatimTextOutput()` and transforming the output with `as.character()`, both unsuccessfully.

I realize it would be easier to just create the value boxes inside the server function with the appropriate class. But in my real application I actually need the value box to persist since it contains other elements that are not updated.

Is there a way to remove the container from `textOutput()` to make this work? Or does changing the class require the use of style tags?

Comment: server-side rendering using `renderUI`would be the easiest. But you stated it wouldn't work on the real world app. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, the `renderUI`-path was my original approach that I had to give up because I include an `actionLink` in the box to trigger updates. Its value is being reset by `renderUI` so that I cannot keep track of it. Your shinyjs-solution is the way to go in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution to dynamically change the css class would be to use `shinyjs`. To use this, you would need to:

1. call `useShinyjs` in the UI
2. add an id to your card
3. get a reactive of the value : ie `value`
4. update the css in the server

It would look something like that:

```
library(shinyjs)

test_df <- tibble(id = 1:2, 
                  title = c("low value","high value"), 
                  value = c(30, 80))

ui <- page_fixed(
  # invoce Shinyjs:
  useShinyjs(), 
  selectInput("select_id", "Selected ID", choices = 1:2, selected = 1),
  value_box(id = "card1", # set an ID
            title = textOutput("vbox_title"),
            value = textOutput("vbox_value"),
            class = NULL
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  subset_df <- reactive({
    test_df %>%
      filter(id == input$select_id)
  })
  # Pull reactive here:
  value <- reactive({subset_df() %>% pull(value)})
  
  output$vbox_value <- renderText({
    value()
  })
  
  output$vbox_title <- renderText({
    subset_df() %>%
      pull(title)
  })

  #update CSS class
  observeEvent(value(),{
    if (value() > 50) {
      removeCssClass(id = "card1", class = "bg-warning")
      addCssClass(id = "card1",class = "bg-success")
    }else if(value() <= 50){
      removeCssClass(id = "card1", class = "bg-success")
      addCssClass(id = "card1",class = "bg-warning")
    }
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Another easy solution to the problem would be using `renderUI`and rendering the whole thing on the server. This would look somthing like that:

```
ui <- page_fixed(
  selectInput("select_id", "Selected ID", choices = 1:2, selected = 1),
  uiOutput("vbox")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  subset_df <- reactive({
    test_df %>%
      filter(id == input$select_id)
  })
  output$vbox <- renderUI({
    value_box(
      title = subset_df()$title,
      value = subset_df()$value,
      class = ifelse(subset_df()$value > 50, "bg-success", "bg-warning")
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```